# Leetcode 95. Unique Binary Search Trees II - Need help understanding the time complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, catalan

I have a question about understanding the time complexity of the code below. It is the code to generate all unique BST for numbers from 1 to n. I have attached an image of how they describe the time complexity using catalan numbers.

[image]It is from leetcode:

> Given an integer n, return all the structurally unique BST's (binary search trees), which has exactly n nodes of unique values from 1 to n. Return the answer in any order.

In the solutions it says the time complexity the catalan numbers * n. Why are we trying to express time complexity of an algorithm to generate all the unique BSTs by looking at the total number of BSTs (I read that catalan numbers is the total number of unique BSTs)? Rather than looking at the total number of unique BSTs, shouldn't we look at how much work the algorithm is doing? Shouldn't the time complexity be O(n * 2^n) since we have n numbers to choose from each time to be a root and then we recurse two times, once to create the left child and once to create the right child?

I might be wrong here but I would appreciate any help in breaking down the time complexity of this algorithm.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def generateTrees(self, n: int) -> List[Optional[TreeNode]]:        
        arr = list(range(0, n))
        def bt( l, r):
            if l > r:
                
                return [None]
            if l == r:
                return [TreeNode(arr[l]+1)]
            
            else:
                output = []
                for i in range(l , r+1):
                    le = bt(l, i-1)
                    ri = bt(i + 1, r)
                    for x in le:
                        for y in ri:
                            node = TreeNode(arr[i] + 1)
                            node.left = x
                            node.right = y
                            output.append(node)
                return output
        return bt(0, n-1)
```

Comment: If you want us to interpret the remarks about Catalan numbers, then please provide a quotation of the exact remarks.

Comment: Hi so the remarks is  "Time complexity : The main computations are to construct all possible trees with a given root, that is actually Catalan number G_n 
 This is done n times, that results in time complexity n * G_n"


@JohnBollinger

Comment: @JohnKugelman what would be a tighter bound then?

Comment: @MushahidNawazKhan, you are confusing your Johns.  I'm not the one who remarked about the bound.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry about that haha i fixed the tags :P

Comment: Nevertheless, the remark about the Catalan numbers does sound misleading.  *C_n* is (among other things) the number of distinct rooted binary trees with *n* nodes.  But there is only one way to fit *n* distinct elements to a given *n*-node rooted tree to form a BST, so *C_n* is the total number of trees to generate, not *nC_n*.  On the other hand, it costs at least *Ω(n)* to construct and output an *n*-node tree, and you need to construct *C_n* of them, so *Ω(nC_n)* is a *lower* bound on the time complexity of any program that solves the problem.